# How to filter messages in apache camel

Tags: filter, apache-camel

In my application build using apache camel (mavenized, spring dsl) , i am reading messages from
a queue, about 3/5 of the messages need to be discarded based on some conditions in data in payload.

But i am new to apache camel and dont know how to call a bean's method and based on
return value (boolean) , if true forward the message to next bean for processing.

JMS queue => Filter (Bean's method) => (true) =>Bean(process data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see the [message filter pattern](http://camel.apache.org/message-filter.html)

```
from("jms:queue:start")
    .filter().method(MyBean.class, "isGoldCustomer").to("bean:process");

public static class MyBean {
    public boolean isGoldCustomer(@Header("level") String level) { 
        return level.equals("gold"); 
    }
}
```